# Running shp2pgsql in Azure cloud shell

Tags: postgresql, azure, postgis

I'm working with an Azure Postgresql database and am using the Cloud Shell to run psql scripts without problems. I'm now trying to load some shp files via the `shp2pgsql` command. The cloud shell responds by:

`bash: shp2pgsql: command not found`

Is it possible at all to use `shp2pgsql` with the Cloud Shell or I'm missing something? I've already successfully created the `postgis` extension on the Postgresql server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems that you cannot run the shp2pgsql command in the Azure Cloud Shell. It is just an interactive, browser-accessible shell for managing Azure resources. Not integrated with too much tool in it because of its flexibility. You can get more details about the features from the [Features & tools for Azure Cloud Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/overview).

I suggest if you want to do something complicated, you'd better run it in a specific Azure VM for yourself. Hope this will be helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks for the info - so I assume if I want to use shapefile data and still want to make them accessible in the Azure Postgres db I'd have to load them in a VM and use something like pg_dump to move them over to Azure.

Comment: Yeah, that's the way.